# Text over an image in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, z-index

I currently have a problem with my z-index with IE.

I have a div, an image in this div and some text over this image.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<section id="content_right">

                    <div class="mini_bloc_image">
                        <img alt="Camionnette VCI" src="img/mini_reparation_site_nb.png" />
                        <span><a href="#">R&eacute;paration sur site</a></span>
                        <span>Nous nous d&eacute;pla&ccedil;ons</span>
                    </div>
```

and the CSS:

```
#content_right {
width: 230px;
height: 484px;
float: right;
}

.mini_bloc_image {
height: 148px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
position: relative;
}

.mini_bloc_image > img {
position: absolute;
}

.mini_bloc_image > span:first-of-type {
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 95px;
left: 0px;
font-size: 1.1em;
background-color: #ffffff;
padding: 4px 5px 4px 5px;
}

.mini_bloc_image > span:last-of-type {
display: block;
top: 95px;
left: 0px;
position: absolute;
left: 50px;
top: 125px;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 1.1em;
font-family: 'Marck Script', cursive;
}
```

IE don't understand my text must be OVER the image...

I found some solutions like this http://www.adrenatie.com/z-index-et-ie6/ or this http://systembash.com/content/css-z-index-internet-explorer/ but it don't works.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Are you asking specifically about IE6?

Comment: Do you really need :first-of-type and :last-of-type?

Comment: I guess yes, because they don't have the same font and apparence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is you're dealing with `span`s, which are rendered inline by default. If you use `display:block`, the z-index will be used:

```
.mini_bloc_image > span:first-of-type {
display: block;
position: absolute;
z-index: 10;
font-size: 1.1em;
background-color: #ffffff;
padding: 4px 5px 4px 5px;
margin-top: 95px;
}

.mini_bloc_image > span:last-of-type {
display: block;
position: absolute;
z-index: 10;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 1.1em;
font-family: 'Marck Script', cursive;
margin-left: 30%;
margin-top: 125px;
}
```

For more about inline elements and positioning, see [this article](http://www.vision.to/articles/the-difference-between-the-flow-and-positioning-for-web-pages.php).

Comment: @Greg Also note, IE has a "bug" where z-index stack will reset.  I don't think this is the issue you're experiencing and Prutswonder's solution looks right.  But if you experiance z-index issues it could also be that a parent's element doesn't have a z-index and child-elements z-index will not override elements higher up the DOM tree.  This often happens with drop-down menus and I believe it's an IE 6, 7 and perhaps 8 issue.   I believe IE 9 doesn't have this problem.  Just as a side note.

Comment: Just for the record, you don't need the z-index in this case, because your spans are after the image in the HTML and in the DOM tree. As a rule of thumb, you only need to tamper with the z-index if the positioning isn't following the flow of the DOM tree.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it, i also tried do replace my spans by divs, but it didn't work. My text is always under my image.. Thanks for the nice article, too. [EDIT: I just read Fozzyuw's comment and I try something]

Comment: Just noticed that you're using a `position:absolute`, but you're not setting a position. That might be why the text is displayed below your image. Try using `left` and `top` to set the text positions. ;-)

Comment: Well.. I sorry, but it still don't work, I must do something wrong. I changed: the block display, top, left and I deleted z-index (useless, as you said). I changed my initial post, if you want to see...

Comment: Just for precision: this code works good on Firefox, Chrome and Safari. Even in mobile version.. --'

Comment: Problem is that IE doesn't support `first-of-type` and `last-of-type`. If you replace those with class names or use jQuery, then it will work.

Comment: What version of IE is causing the problem?  Prutswonder is correct that you have to be careful of what CSS selectors and rules are applicable to the version of IE you're targeting.  http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html can help finding CSS compatibility.  I believe some items, such as Flash/plugins, always render above all other things in older browsers (I'm thinking IE6?).  I don't think images should have this issue though.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works, the problem was first-of-type and last-of-type.